# Where are these functions are stored in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Where is the function sysdate stored, and in what package, e.g:

```
select sysdate from dual;
select systimestamp from dual;
```

Also, take this query:

```
select sys.login_user,sys.database_name ,sys.sysevent from dual;
```

- what is sys here?
- Is it a package?
- where is this package stored?
- can I view the source(text) in this package **please provide me the query**?

Answer (score 3):

SYSDATE and SYSTIMESTAMP are functions in the STANDARD package owned by SYS.  However, this is a special package and so you don't need to specify standard.sysdate (in fact, you can't!)

You can view this package like this:

```
select text
from   all_source
where owner='SYS'
and name='STANDARD'
and type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
order by line;
```

Answer (score 0):

sys is a schema.
sysdate is a glovbally available variable containing the current date/time.

Comment: +.5 for sys, -.5 for saying sysdate is a variable